# Codility 'Tape Equilibrium' task (0% Performance)

Tags: php, performance, task

Can anyone tell me why is this PHP code 100% correct, but takes 0% performance on Codility?

```
function solution($A)
   {
       $N = count($A);
       $D = [];
       for ($i=1;$i<$N;$i++){
             $A2 = array_slice($A,$i); //вторая часть
             $sum2 = array_sum($A2);
             $sum1 = array_sum($A) - $sum2;
             $diff = $sum1 - $sum2;
             $D[$i-1] = abs($diff);      
       }
       sort($D);
       $result = $D[0];
       return $result;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting which is O(NlogN). 
No need to sort, if you keep the minimum difference at each iteration:
`mindiff = min(min, diff)` you can simply return diff.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some array functions like array_sum and array_splice that are called on each iteration, with the increasing number of elements, It causes program to take more time doing splices and sums.

Check the following solution the code is self explanatory, it simply adds the value to left side total  and removes the elements value from right total. The variables inside loop can be further simplified. But they are added separately so that they make sense.

P.s the code has 100% result at codility.

```
function solution($a){
     
     $leftSum = $a[0];
     $rightSum = array_sum($a) - $a[0];
     
     $diffArr[] = abs( $leftSum  - $rightSum);
     
     for($i=1; $i < sizeof($a)-1 ;  $i++)
     {

          $additionToLeft = $a[$i];
          $newLeft =  $leftSum + $additionToLeft;
          $newRight =  $rightSum - $additionToLeft;
          
          $leftSum = $newLeft;
          $rightSum = $newRight;
          
          $difference = abs( $leftSum - $rightSum);
          $diffArr[] =  $difference;
     }
    
   return min($diffArr);

}
```